# iOs7 'Web App' using localstorage launch Home screen is not working

Tags: ios7, local-storage, fullscreen, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have some issues with saving data in local storage when my HTML5 application is added from home screen in iOs7.
 Base on this post [here](http://blog.nsbasic.com/2012/09/important-io6-and-data-storage/) i see that the home screen application is like native and its not using safari's local storage, but i need a workaround for this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its a localStorage issue? I'm using localStorage all the time and never had problems with Home screen apps. You can use Safari to debug the Home screen app. There you will see any errors in the console. You can also step debug through the localStorage part

Comment: no errors in the log just everytime i launch my app from home screen local storage is cleared, and this is only in ios7. I didn't clear localStorage for sure because in all other platforms its working fine. There must be something special there :/

Comment: Remember that Home screen apps will not "see" what you store in ordinary Safari (even though it's the same site). If you store something via the Home Screen app, and then reopen it, is the localStorage still cleared?

Comment: yeah, at every launch localStore is cleared

Comment: I have given some history and some options in an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292179/564726