# My iOS web-app users keep getting logged out

Tags: ios, node.js, session, session-cookies, remember-me

Sessions are working great on desktop and Android. I'm running a NodeJS app with:

this in my `<head>`:

```
<meta name='mobile-web-app-capable' content="yes">
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content="yes">
```

`express-session` with mongostore:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_STORE_SECRET,
  store: mongoStore,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

passport session and `remember-me`:

```
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(passport.authenticate('remember-me'));
```

...but several users have reported that they're getting logged out every day. They say they don't have issues with other websites, such as facebook.

Any ideas for what I'm missing? Again, it works fine on Android etc.

Comment: I believe its a bug with iOS Keychain that stores all passwords/cookies and other sensitive data. I have had the same issue with my iOS apps and other apps that I use on iOS 10. One thing that worked for me, was updating to the latest version of iOS 10. (Well it worked for a while anyway...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS7 Safari: Saving to Home-screen and persist token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109615/ios7-safari-saving-to-home-screen-and-persist-token)